# Installed new iTunes, songs in "Music" aren't displaying

Tags: itunes

I've installed the new iTunes and I can't see my songs when I click on Music on the sidebar.

I tried re-adding the folder to my library but it's still not there. But the weird thing is it appears on the recently added playlist. How can I make my songs show on music again?

Answer (score 0):

iTunes keeps a backup database of previous iTunes Libraries in the Music folder. Hopefully this [KB Article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1451) can help you out.